# Yeoman does not recognize input - windows 10

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I run into some weird problem. I've installed Yeoman and 'code' generator. When I'm trying to select an option in the first menu I can do it, but the next one is not responding to any inputs.

For example: I'm typing in the cmd 'yo code' then I'm choosing 'New Color Theme' and after that I can't type anything, I can't choose an option, even <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> can't handle this.

Does anyone knows how to fix this? Haven't found any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

had the same problem, uninstall yo and install at version 1.8.4